# How to send information (return) from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I'm currently trying to code a dumb website for a class. I'm trying to access my PHP file to check if the name exists inside the database or not. When it does, it needs to return either a 1 or 0 back to the javascript part. Is there a real way to do that?

The reason for the return is in case the name does exist, it will just send an alert to the user that hey the name exists, move along.

Note I'm using the tutorials from w3school.com in case my code looks like some amateur level sh*t.

javascript:

```
function checking(){
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "checker.php?firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname, true);
                xmlhttp.send(); 
                alert (queue);
            }
```

php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
    $lastname  = $_GET['lastname'];
    $yes = 1;
    $no = 0;
    //Information needed in order to access database
    $dbname = "**********************";
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "************************";
    $password = "************";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql_query = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM queue_1 WHERE firstname='".$firstname."' and lastname='".$lastname."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($row == 1){
        echo ($yes);
    }
    else
    {
        echo ($no);
    }
?>
```

Comment: In order to have PHP communicate with JavaScript, you need to `echo` the information out onto the page from PHP (possibly in a hidden `<div>`), then use something like `getElementById()` in JavaScript to retrieve it. *However*, if you're making the initial call from JavaScript itself, you can simply use AJAX (like `XMLHttpRequest`) and check the `response`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues here, your JS code is attempting to access an undefined variable (at least in the context of the function you posted) `queue`.

Outside of your PHP code, make sure that the JS is handling the **response** coming from PHP, do this by attaching an event listener to your request.
The load event will trigger when your PHP script completes, you can point this to a named function if your code will be more complex than just an alert.

More info here [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

```
function checking(){ 
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest() ;
    xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", function () {
        alert(this.responseText);
    });
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "checker.php?firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

This is under the assumption that you're trying to display the response text as an alert message.

Additionally, beware passing unfiltered user input  into an SQL query, this can lead to injection attacks, I'd suggest you change your PHP code to use prepared statements from the mysqli lib.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql_query = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM queue_1 WHERE firstname=? AND lastname =?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_query) ;

$stmt->bind_param('s', $firstname);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $lastname);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();
echo $stmt->num_rows === 1 ? $yes : $no;
$stmt->free_result() ;
$stmt->close() ;
```

More info about mysqli can be found here if some of this is confusing [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

And on a  final note, on your sql if you are looking for the existence of a record only, it tends to be faster to do `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE fieldname=? LIMIT 1` as you are not using the result set for this.